# How to add another digit to the results of a json decode?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a ticker on the top of my website.

Right now the results display `2.14`

The api I'm calling gives me an extra digit but its not displaying.

The results should be displaying `2.147`

Here's some of the code I'm working with.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$symbol[$i] = $obj->results[0]->symbol;
$open[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->open, 2, '.', ',');
$high[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->high, 2, '.', ',');
$low[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->low, 2, '.', ',');
$close[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close, 2, '.', ',');
$gap[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close - $obj->results[0]->close, 2, '.', ',');
$percent[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close / $obj->results[0]->close, 2, '.', ',');
```

How can I make the ticker display the third digit after the decimal?

Comment: In the `number_format()` change the `2` to `3`?

Comment: Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all the `2` values (which represent 2 decimal places) to `3` (which is the 3 decimal places that you want).

Basically the second attribute show's the number of decimal places you'd like to format your result to.

Here are the docs:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

This is what your code should look like:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$symbol[$i] = $obj->results[0]->symbol;
$open[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->open, 3, '.', ',');
$high[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->high, 3, '.', ',');
$low[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->low, 3, '.', ',');
$close[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close, 3, '.', ',');
$gap[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close - $obj->results[0]->close, 3, '.', ',');
$percent[$i] = number_format($obj->results[1]->close / $obj->results[0]->close, 3, '.', ',');
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)